# SVG images not being clipped to width of SVG container in IE11

Tags: html, svg, icons, internet-explorer-11

When displaying some SVG icons within an SVG of a fixed width, they should be clipped to the width of that SVG container.

In all sensible browsers this works fine but in IE11 the icons extend beyond the width of the container.

Is there any workaround to counter this behaviour?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <svg class="task" width="50">
        <rect class="task-rectangle" fill="#FFE5E5" width="50" height="50"></rect>
        <svg class="svgs-using-def-with-image-href" x="4" y="5">
            <use href="#GreenTick" x="0"/>
            <use href="#Triangle" x="18"/>
            <use href="#Facebook" x="36"/>
        </svg>

        <svg class="reusable-icons" width="0" height="0">
            <defs>
                <svg id="GreenTick" width="18" height="18">
                    <image href="https://svgur.com/i/XvH.svg" width="18" height="18"/>
                </svg>
                <svg id="Triangle" width="18" height="18">
                    <image href="https://svgur.com/i/XwA.svg" width="18" height="18"/>
                </svg>
                <svg id="Facebook" width="18" height="18">
                    <image href="https://svgur.com/i/Xx8.svg" width="18" height="18"/>
                </svg>
            </defs>
        </svg>
    </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

IE11: [image] Chrome: [image]

Comment: Don't nest SVG tags - more people are doing this now, but browsers don't test for this use case - and people are running into lots of bugs. Use the g element instead.

Comment: try setting overflow="hidden" explicitly on the svg tag of the overflowing content. This is the default but perhaps IE needs a nudge.

Comment: @MichaelMullany I don't see why you wouldn't nest SVGs, you seriously limit your options using only g elements and I've never seen or read anything to say it's a bad idea. For prosperity I changed it to have no nested svg elements and only use a g element. Same problem occurs.

Comment: @RobertLongson I did experiment with adding overflow="hidden" at various levels, no change in functionality doesn't appear to honour it.

Comment: you might need to define and use an explicit clip-path then.

Comment: @drevans - I'm seeing more questions on the SVG tag where the solution is "stop nesting SVG tags" (that's my observation at least)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE9-11 & Edge don't properly scale SVG files. You can add height, width, viewBox and CSS rules as workarounds.

I tried the `overflow` CSS style mentioned, and it works fine.  How do you test the code? The reason it doesn't work in your side may be related to the browser cache, please try to clear IE cache and test again.

---

**Edit:** I refer to the code you provide, and it has such a problem: If you use the `<g>` element, I think you also need to use `clip` CSS to achieve the same effect.

This is a simple sample:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <svg class="resource-row" data-level="1" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="576" overflow="hidden">
        <g class="task" overflow="hidden" clip-path="url(#clip)">
            <rect class="task-rectangle" fill="#FFE5E5" width="50" height="50"></rect>
            <svg class="svgs-using-def-with-image-href" x="4" y="5" width="46" overflow="hidden">
                <use href="#GreenTick" x="0" />
                <use href="#Triangle" x="18" />
                <use href="#Facebook" x="36" />
            </svg>
        </g>
    </svg>
    <svg class="reusable-icons" width="0" height="0">
        <defs>
            <rect class="task-rectangle" id="rect" width="50" height="50"></rect>
            <clipPath id="clip">
                <use xlink:href="#rect" />
            </clipPath>
            <svg id="GreenTick" width="18" height="18">
                <image href="https://svgur.com/i/XvH.svg" width="18" height="18" />
            </svg>
            <svg id="Triangle" width="18" height="18">
                <image href="https://svgur.com/i/XwA.svg" width="18" height="18" />
            </svg>
            <svg id="Facebook" width="18" height="18">
                <image href="https://svgur.com/i/Xx8.svg" width="18" height="18" />
            </svg>
        </defs>
    </svg> 
</body>
</html>
```

Result in IE 11:

[image]

Comment: Now that is interesting! It does indeed work for this example and I wonder whether there is something to this. 

However, when I applied the `overflow` attribute on the real world code which is considerably more complicated with many more levels it still exhibits the same problem. The task `svg` in our real problem is really a `g` element, with many more `g` elements above it until we do eventually hit an `svg`. I simply removed all those levels to make the example more concise.

Simply putting one `g` element level in the chain to wrap the `rect` and `svg` and the problem comes back.

Comment: Annoyingly I can't comment the HTML but here is a codepen link with the modified HTML with overflow specified exhibiting the same problem in IE. [Codepen](https://codepen.io/drevans112/pen/oNZPvXj)

Comment: @drevans I've edited my answer and edited the code according to your Codepen, please check it.

Comment: Yesterday I was experimenting with `clipPath` based on the comment from @RobertLongson. I reached the same conclusion only difference being I embedded the `rect` within the `clipPath`:

`<clipPath id="myClip" ><rect height="18" width="46"/></clipPath>`